# Django : Fail to redirecting main page after deleting object

Tags: python, django, redirect, web

I was trying to make deleting comments function, when user clicks button then it deletes relevant item and redirects to main page. However I got this error message and I'm spending time to fix this. Please review my code and if there is something wrong.

error message

```
UnboundLocalError at /blog/detail/18/
local variable 'context' referenced before assignment
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def delete_comment(request, comment_no):
    comment = Comment.objects.get(pk=comment_no).delete()
    return redirect('blog/home.html')
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^delete_comment/(?P<comment_no>[0-9]+)/$', views.delete_comment, name='delete_comment'),
```

templates

```
<form action="{% url 'blog:delete_comment' %}" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="hidden" name="comment_no" value="{{ comments.comment_no }}" />
       <button type="submit">delete</button>
</form>
```

**EDIT 01**

I added def detail in views.py

```
@login_required
def detail(request, article_no):
   if not request.user.is_authenticated():
       return redirect_to_login(next, 'blog/login.html')
   else:
       user = request.user

    if 'username' in request.session:
        username = request.session['username']
        item = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=article_no)
        item.hit = Article.objects.filter(pk=article_no).update(hit = item.hit+1)
        no = article_no
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(article_no=article_no)
        context = {
             'item': item,
             'comments': comments,
            }
    return render(request, 'blog/detail.html', context)
```

Comment: Can you share the view method for detail? The error specifies there's something wrong in there

Comment: @Fallen I added detail method in views.py.

Comment: Is that the exact indentation you used in your `def detail`? Your second `if` block is slightly misaligned.

Answer (score 1):

```
if 'username' in request.session:
    ...
    context = {
         'item': item,
         'comments': comments,
        }
```

Here, the `context` is only created `if 'username' in request.session` is `True`.

Since you're returning a `context` variable, you'll need to create it for the case when `username` is not in `request.session` too. Otherwise `context` will be missing if the above codeblock returns `False`, and subsequently cause that `UnboundLocalError`.